# Javascript: как самым простым способом проверить, что переменная содержит строку и эта строка непустая?

Tags: javascript

Есть переменная содержащая какое-то значение. Нужно условие, которые бы возвращало true если переменная содержит непустую строку и false во всех остальных случаях.

Внимание!: false во всех случаях, кроме непустой строки. То есть если переменная содержит true, то выражение должно возвращать false. Если переменная содержит 1, то выражение должно возвращать false.

Эту проверку можно сделать например так:

```
typeof var === "string" && var !== ""
```

Но такое условие выглядит довольно длинным. В JS вроде как много разного синтаксического сахара, который позволяет делать сразу несколько проверок одним оператором. Например:

```
typeof var == "string" && var == "abc"  эквивалетно  var === "abc"

typeof var != "string" || var != "abc"  эквивалетно  var !== "abc"
```

Может быть есть короткая форма записи для такого условия:

```
typeof var == "string" && var != ""
```

или такого:

```
typeof var == "string" && var.length > 0
```

?

Comment: Обернуть это  в короткую функцию и использовать.

Comment: Если хочется еще меньше, то `var !== ""` -> `!!var`

Comment: !!var будет возвращать true для var === true. А надо, чтобы возвращал false.

Comment: Те кто минусуют и голосуют за закрытие вопроса могут как-то пояснить свою позицию? Я думал, что если в JS есть синтаксический сахар в виде операторов === и !== которые проверяют одновременно тип и значение на равенство, то наверное есть и другой сахар, или может другой способ использования этих операторов который проверяет тип на равенство, а значение на непустоту.

Comment: Ну или может быть я не понимаю идей заложенных в JS и неправильно его использую. Тогда что я делаю не так?

Comment: Начинаю ненавидеть золотую метку по JS)) Почему она не даёт выбрать проголосовать за закрытие или единолично закрыть?)) Тем не менее ответ в дубле всё  равно есть и он простой

Comment: `!!var будет возвращать true для var === true`, я же не говорил, что нужно убрать первое условие :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Личная закрывашка срабатывает только при указании дубликата. Во всех остальных причинах закрытия, работает обычное голосование)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME знаю, но всё равно непорядок))